# Please break up this sentence into several sentences

Tags: sentence

[image]

> In the Lung Opacity images we can see that there is haziness were the labeled boxes are (termed ground glass opacity) and/or a loss of the usual boundries of the lungs (termed consolidation).

It is confusing to understand this sentence. Specifically, i couldn't get which is the subject of "were labeled boxes"

Comment: It looks like a typo of “where” with a missing “h”.

Comment: Lawrence is right. It should be the preposition "where" not the verb "were". The expression "where the labeled boxes are (termed ground glass opacity) and/or a loss of the usual boundries of the lungs (termed consolidation)" is thus a preposition phrase, not a verb phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is best rectified with the following changes:

"In the Lung Opacity images, we can see that there is a haziness where the labeled boxes are (termed ground glass opacity) and/or a loss of the usual boundaries of the lungs (termed consolidation)."

Someone with knowledge in pulmonology and other medically related fields could give a better answer based on context.